# How to setup and teardown with multiple files and test cases in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-bdd

I am new to pytest.
I have 10 test files which has multiple tests defined in each test file like below

```
test_repo
   - features
   -step_defs
      - stress_tests
         -file1 (10 test cases)
         -file2 (3 test cases)
      - functional_tests
        - file2 (2 test cases)
        - file3 (20 test cases)
```

and so on.

My problem statement is - when i initiate stress tests i want to setup and tear down like below

```
   - setup testdb
      - run stress tests file 1 and file2 on testdb
   - tear down delete testdb after all tests are run.
```

So i want to setup creation and deletion of DB only once and run all 13 test cases from stress_tests.

I tried pytest_fixtures(scope="session") they get reused or called upon each test cases.

Is there a way where i can call the creation of db and dleetion of db only once after all tests run completed?

Comment: can you show code of fixture?

Answer (score 0):

Using `session` in fixture scope will be automatically deleted the db after all tests have been run. Based on the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#fixture-scopes) it was said that

> session: the fixture is destroyed at the end of the test session.

So you dont need to worry about delete the database

For creation of the db itself, i think you can achieve this by define the session scoped fixture in shared `conftest.py` module